# Combining multiple SQL Queries into one statement

Tags: sql

I am looking for a way to combine multiple SQL queries to save having to keep calling the database. I have three tables, one with a clubs details, one with the club facilities and the third combines them.

Here is a simple version of the tables:

t1

```
id, name, city
1, curby, London
2, zoo, Birmingham
```

t2

```
id, facility
1, bar
2, function suite
3, VIP room
```

t3

```
id, club_id, facility_id
1, 2, 1
2, 2, 3
3, 1, 2
4, 2, 2
```

In all of the above the first columns (id) are just unique identifiers, and I am using commas to show you where each field separates. What I would like to get from the database is something like:

```
1, curby, London, function suite
2, zoo, Birmingham, bar, VIP room, function suite
```

If any one has any ideas please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on `JOINs`. You didn't say what RDMS you're using, but this is what I'd use in Oracle:

```
SELECT t3.id, t2.name, t2.city, t3.facility
  FROM t3
 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t3.facility_id
 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t3.club_id
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so t1 is the club, t2 is a list of facilties, and t3 assigns a facility to a club, right?

You can use the JOIN (INNER or OUTER) syntax to get data from multiple tables at once.  A OUTER JOIN  is used when there can be data in the parent table (t1) but nothing in the child table (t2).  An INNER JOIN is used when you only want records with data in both tables.

You also must include an "ON" clause that indicates how the two tables are joined together:

```
SELECT t1.id as club_id, t1.name as club_name, t2.facility as facility_name
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON
    t2.club_id=t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON
    t3.id=f2.facility_id
```

Also, I would actually change the names of the tables if I were you, to something that better represents the data held in the table.

Comment: Although this will return multiple records (one per each club-facility combination).

Answer (score 0):

Consider renaming:

- `t1` to `Clubs` and its `id` to `club_id`;
- `t2` to `Facilities` and its `id` to `facility_id`;
- `t3` to `ClubFacilities` and dropping its needless `id` column.

Then you could write

```
SELECT Clubs.*, facility
  FROM Clubs 
       NATURAL JOIN Facilities 
       NATURAL JOIN ClubFacilities;
```